# Can I get email id, which email id is used to login in webmaster?

Tags: google-search-console, email, authentication

Can I get email id, which email id is used to login in webmaster... please help... We Have all email id and passwords @admin... But I dont know which is used to login webmaster... What I can do in it... ?